# Register new user in the frontend

Tags: users, front-end

I hava a big form and when a user fill it I need to create a new user in Wordpress from there.

Its posible to create and user from the frontend and add some custom information?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. What have you tried already? Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.

The relevant functions to do this are:

- [`wp_create_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) Creates a user given a user/pass/email
- [`wp_insert_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) Creates or updates a user given user/pass/email
- [`add_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) Adds User Meta ( same as Post Meta/Custom fields but for users rather than posts )

You'll find examples on how to use those functions, and links to more possibly relevant functions. Use these functions in your form handling code on submission, make sure to escape all values entered.

Comment: Thanks, finally I solve my problem with `wp_insert_user`.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're looking for a top to bottom tutorial you can check out this one:
http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/

There are also plugins that solve this problem.